# Where is the download(curl/wget) package in docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In the DockerFile, it has the sample codes:

```
RUN curl https://collectd.org/files/collectd-5.5.0.tar.gz | tar zxf - &&\ 
cd collectd* &&\ 
./configure  &&\ 
grep -rl /proc/ . | xargs sed -i "s/\/proc\//\/host\/proc\//g" &&\ 
make all install
```

What the codes do is to download the software 'collectd' and unzip it, then to install it.

The 'collectd' installed sucessful, but where is the downloaded software store? Specifically, where is the collectd?

Thanks for help.

Comment: By default, your working directory is `/`, unless you've changed it with `WORKDIR`.

Comment: Thanks, @larsks. I found it in /.